# Checking total order on C++11 enum class (how to implement operator<)

Tags: c++, class, enums, state

Often in writing simple state machines you have a total order such as:

```
State {
  initial,
  connecting,
  established,
  ready,
  closed,
  failed
}
```

You can test a given value for equivalence easily:

```
if (state == State::established)
```

But what if your state is *ready* -- this test would fail, even if being ready implies being *established*? The alternative would be to add another clause, but with longer lists, or changing requirements this could become longer.

```
if (state == State::established || state == State::ready || ...)
```

And with a C-style enum you can even determine relative ordering by converting to integers:

```
if (state > State::established && state <= State::closed)
```

But if you want to enjoy the type-safety enum class except for the addition of operator< you appear to be out of luck. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the actual problem you are having?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement `operator<` and `operator>` for a C++11 scoped enum?

Comment: Yes! Sorry if the original wording was poor. First timer.

Comment: You could consider adding that phrasing into the question. I think it's very clear and direct.

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to either use a bitmask or to create a dedicated State class to handle this, rather than trying to hack the scoped enum into something that it's not.  Using numerical comparisons on enums is probably pretty bad form anyway, as an enum is intended to uniquely identify a named value and nothing more.

Comment: @Taywee agreed it's a bit of a hack -- but possibly a helpful one?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, scoped enums offer type safety because they can't be implicitly converted to integers.

But nothing prevents you from casting enum to integer:

```
if ((int)state > (int)State::established && (int)state <= (int)State::closed)
```

You can use either C-style cast of `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to just define the operators I need as inline functions, using static_cast as necessary to get the values to compare:

```
enum class MyEnum : unsigned { ALPHA, BETA, DELTA, EPSILON };
inline bool operator<(MyEnum a, MyEnum b)  { return static_cast<unsigned>(a) < static_cast<unsigned>(b); }
inline bool operator>(MyEnum a, MyEnum b)  { return static_cast<unsigned>(a) > static_cast<unsigned>(b); }
inline bool operator<=(MyEnum a, MyEnum b) { return static_cast<unsigned>(a) <= static_cast<unsigned>(b); }
inline bool operator>=(MyEnum a, MyEnum b) { return static_cast<unsigned>(a) >= static_cast<unsigned>(b); }
```

(Note: In C++20, this will get simpler because you can just define one operator, the "<=>" operator, and get the others generated automatically.)

In cases where I need to do more complex tricks, I can use a static std::unordered_map to map the values (or pairs of values) to whatever I need:

```
#include <unordered_map>

const std::string& getName(MyEnum e)
{
   static const std::string UNKNOWN = "???";
   static const std::unordered_map<MyEnum, std::string> NAMES = {
      {MyEnum::ALPHA,   "ALPHA"},
      {MyEnum::BETA,    "BETA"},
      {MyEnum::DELTA,   "DELTA"},
      {MyEnum::EPSILON, "EPSILON"},
   };
   const auto it = NAMES.find(e);
   return ((it != NAMES.end()) ? it->second : UNKNOWN);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One might argue this is a flawed request since having a total order on enumerated values was a historical accident of implementation method, or that state machines are rarely linear (*failed* implies *closed*, but *failed* doesn't necessarily imply the connection was ever *ready*).

However I've found it comes up just often enough to have a solution until you move to something more sophisticated (or your state machine grows). I came up with the following solution that doesn't require converting the enum to an integer value.

```
bool has_reached(State current, State condition)
{
    bool reached = false;
    switch (condition)
    {
    case State::initial:     reached |= current == State::initial;
    case State::connecting:  reached |= current == State::connecting;
    case State::established: reached |= current == State::established;
    case State::ready:       reached |= current == State::ready;
    case State::closed:      reached |= current == State::closed;
    case State::failed:      reached |= current == State::failed;
    };
    return reached;
}
```

To be used as follows:

```
if (has_reached(state, State::established)) // State::ready returns true
```

It should be fast on modern systems and hard to get wrong -- as long as you don't mix up the declared and switch orders.

Comment: "I came up with the following solution that doesn't require converting to integer" - ...lol. Really? Who told you that?

Comment: @WhiZTiM: "Really" what?

Comment: @Ryan: Subjective but I prefer omitting the `default` case and paying attention to warnings, than being surprised by an `assert` five months down the line when the bug is suddenly randomly triggered. Shame there's no `static_assert` equivalent for this though. Huh, that would make a good proposal come to think of it..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... Ryan says his solution doesn't require converting to an integer... Enums are typically [treated](https://godbolt.org/g/x2dv12) as `int`s

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True -- depends on the system and your testing, and tolerance for error.

Comment: This is an overdone equivalent of `static_cast<int>(current) >= static_cast<int>(condition)`.

Comment: You'll want to `break` before falling through to the default case. Though personally I'd prefer simply casting to integer instead of all this.

Comment: @WhiZTiM: What? OP is asking about scoped enums. Do you know what a scoped enum is?

Comment: @Ryan FYI https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/cDJNF2afAs4

Comment: @Taywee this version depends on the implementation of has_reached for correctness, not integral value. You can modify linearly the implies relationship without using artificial numeric values. It reads as it's intended.

Comment: @RyanMcDougall This version of has_reached still depends entirely on order, it's just not literally defined by the underlying integrer type, and you've just moved the order dependency out of the enum and into this function.  Not only that, but this function will fail every time and abort the program, as it always  falls through to the default condition, because you don't break out of any of the case statements.  Even if you didn't have the assert, the performance could be much better, as it redundantly falls through all following case statements even after a successful match.

Comment: @Taywee hah, the one change from the version in use! A superscalar CPU can evaluate the equivalencies in parallel, but the accumulator value is a data dependency it's true. A lot of if-else I'm not sure is any better performance wise, especially on a CPU with poor branch prediction. But yes, it's designed to be more literal within the intended idiom than an cast to magic numbers.

Comment: @interjay the `break` is omitted on purpose, it is supposed to fall through so that the flag is set if the actual condition is anything later in the list of cases than the first one being tested for

Comment: @M.M My comment was posted before the answer was edited, when it would always fall through into the default case which contained `assert(false)`.